# How can I compute the most recent value from a column in a second dataset for each individual?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `values` that looks like:

```
person | date       | value
-------|------------|------
A      | 01-01-2020 | 1
A      | 01-08-2020 | 2
A      | 01-12-2020 | 3
B      | 01-02-2020 | 4
B      | 01-05-2020 | 5
B      | 01-06-2020 | 6
```

And another dataframe `encounters` that looks like:

```
person | date       
-------|------------
A      | 01-01-2020 
A      | 01-03-2020 
A      | 01-06-2020 
A      | 01-11-2020 
A      | 01-12-2020 
A      | 01-15-2020 
B      | 01-01-2020 
B      | 01-04-2020 
B      | 01-06-2020 
B      | 01-08-2020 
B      | 01-09-2020 
B      | 01-10-2020
```

What I'd like to end up with is a merged dataframe that adds a third column to the `encounters` dataset with the most recent value of `value` for the corresponding person (shown below). Is there a straightforward way to do this in pandas?

```
person | date       | most_recent_value
-------|------------|-------------------
A      | 01-01-2020 | 1
A      | 01-03-2020 | 1
A      | 01-06-2020 | 1
A      | 01-11-2020 | 2
A      | 01-12-2020 | 3
A      | 01-15-2020 | 3
B      | 01-01-2020 | None
B      | 01-04-2020 | 4
B      | 01-06-2020 | 6
B      | 01-08-2020 | 6
B      | 01-09-2020 | 6
B      | 01-10-2020 | 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially `merge_asof`:

```
values['date'] = pd.to_datetime(values['date'])
encounters['date'] = pd.to_datetime(encounters['date'])

(pd.merge_asof(encounters.assign(rank=np.arange(encounters.shape[0]))
                         .sort_values('date'), 
              values.sort_values('date'),
              by='person', on='date')
  .sort_values('rank')
  .drop('rank', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   person       date  value
0       A 2020-01-01    1.0
2       A 2020-01-03    1.0
4       A 2020-01-06    1.0
9       A 2020-01-11    2.0
10      A 2020-01-12    3.0
11      A 2020-01-15    3.0
1       B 2020-01-01    NaN
3       B 2020-01-04    4.0
5       B 2020-01-06    6.0
6       B 2020-01-08    6.0
7       B 2020-01-09    6.0
8       B 2020-01-10    6.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much!